# React Native Webview causes Nav bar become transparent

Tags: reactjs, webview, react-native

Not sure if it's a bug. I'm using react native 0.33, when I test my app on nexus 5 (Android 6.0), once the webview opens, the navbar will become transparent.
Then it will recover to black at the next open.

[image]

My code is pretty straightforward:

```
          this.props.navigator.push({
          name: 'web_page',
            passProps:{
              url: news.url,
              title: news.title,
            },
          callback: this.refreshNewsReadStatus.bind(this)
          });
```

Anyone have idea?